# Outlook cannot get currentView reuslt

Tags: c#, outlook

I use outlook API in [How to: Search and Obtain Items in an Aggregated View (Outlook)] (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868826(v=office.15).aspx). When I use GetTable() method, I cannot get results that present in the currentview. The variable currentView always is null. But when set searchtext of explorer.search to null, I get all items in the currentView. Why make this happen?
Thanks.

```
Outlook.Explorer explorer = app.ActiveExplorer();
if (searchTxt == "category")
{
       searchTxt = "";
        explorer.ClearSearch();
 }
 else
   explorer.Search(searchTxt, Outlook.OlSearchScope.olSearchScopeAllFolders);
Outlook.TableView tableview = currentview as Outlook.TableView;

Outlook.Table table = tableview.GetTable();

while (!table.EndOfTable)
 {

            // Then display each row in the Table objsect 
            // that represents an item in the search results. 
      Outlook.Row nextRow = table.GetNextRow();
     Array ct = nextRow.GetValues();
     MessageBox.Show(nextRow["Subject"]);
 }
```

when searchTex is null, MessageBox will show subject.

Comment: Do you have some code for us ?

Comment: I have pasted code, please help to check

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you use a wrong *CurrentView* property. You may find that property defined for the Explorer and Folder classes in the Outlook object model.

Try to use the [CurrentView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff864212(v=office.15).aspx) property of the Folder class instead. Where did you get the *currentview* object?

Comment: I found a sentence in msdn about explorer.search method: there is no programmatic mechanism to obtain the search results. But, I also get a msdn webpage: How to: Search and Obtain Items in an Aggregated View (Outlook). Its content is in contrast, i am confused.

Comment: Yes, there is no straight way for accessing the search results via the Outlook object model. But, as a workaround, you can use the View object for accessing the result set of items found.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question. At first, I am intended to get items by items.Restrict() method and use instant serach by explorer.search() concurrently. But it will not be efficient. Now  your suggestion will  be important to me, I will try this way. thanks!

Comment: there exists delay when i get currentview, but instant search by explorer.search is not over.

Comment: You can set up a timer object and run your code in the first timer's event. As I said, there is no other way to get the search results in Outlook.

Comment: year, I have solved it. Thanks for helping. Another problem, do you know how to get instant search context that users put in. After google and msdn, I didn't find any method or interface to get context from instant search box.